# Deploy HDF using HDP mariadb server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, hdf, hdp

I have an HDP cluster (4 machines) using mysql/mariadb server which is working just fine. I now have to deploy an HDF cluster separated, but using the same mariadb server as the HDP one.

I searched but unfortunately I didn't find any tips in order to solve this.

Can anyway give some ideas or tips/links for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Imeliator. What you describe is a common practice for a small dev or poc cluster when you want to use the same mysql metastore as HDP.  My only advice is to use it on HDF:  you will have to create databases, users, and grants for any of the HDF hosts you want to access the HDP mysql.   This is not to be confused with Ambari's internal Postgres database.

If you need to use an external database for both Ambari's Metastore:

The steps you need to complete are during the setup of Ambari HDF (ambari-server setup).  You need to tell it to use the other database server.  You should follow the documentation for your Ambari versions to complete these steps.   The document will describe creating the database, users ,grants, permissions and creating the initial schema.  For example:

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.1.5/bk_ambari-administration/content/using_ambari_with_mysql.html